# .htaccess rule to force SSL on only certain domains

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I'm running a WordPress multisite network that allows users to optionally use a custom domain name on their websites. Users that opt not to use a custom domain are assigned a subdomain of the WP install (e.g.: fred.example.com, with example.com being the URL the WP multisite network is installed on).

I have a wildcard SSL configured for the main domain, but I do not have certificates available for custom domain names.

What I need is a htaccess rule to force traffic to https if the request is for either `example.com` or `*.example.com`, but not if the request is coming in using a custom domain.

It should work as follows:

- `http://example.com/*` → `https://example.com/*`
- `http://foo.example.com/*` → `https://foo.example.com/*`
- `http://customdomain.com/*` → `http://customdomain.com/*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file. Using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

What this says is... For all requests that are not HTTPS and that match `example.com` or `<subdomain>.example.com` then redirect to `https://` on the same host, same URL-path.

Note that this doesn't allow `www.<subdomain>.example.com` (which I assume your SSL cert does not cover anyway).

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK.

Comment: This creates a 500 Internal Server Error. Syntax error maybe?

Comment: Sorry, that last `RewriteCond` should be `RewriteRule`! (Just updated.)

Comment: So, this works for the root of the main site and subdomains, but for folders/pages in the site, it doesn't redirect. Example: `http://example.com/2017/05/01/hello-world/` doesn't redirect to https

Comment: Umm, it should. Is this rule at the top of your root `.htaccess` file? There's no specific check for the URL-path (folders/pages), so `example.com/` and `example.com/2017/05/01/hello-world/` are the same as regards this directive. Also, make sure your browser cache is clear, in case any earlier (erroneous) 301s are cached.

Comment: That was it... I had it below the WordPress rewrite rules. Thanks!